# Switch between Tabs in Netbeans on Mac?

Tags: macos, netbeans

I feel it annoying to have to mouse click the Tabs in Netbeans when I want to go to another opened file.

Is there key command to navigate to the LEFT and RIGHT on Mac?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> & <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> - [link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/KeymapProfileFor60).

Answer (score 22):

I know this is an old question, but if someone else ends up here looking for the answer:

```
Netbeans -> tools -> options -> keymap

OSX: 
next tab = cmd + page down 
prev tab = cmd + page up

Windows:
next tab = ctlr + page down
prev tab = ctlr + page up
```

note that by default the keymap shortcuts are organised by category and then alphabetically, and not just alphabetically.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem that this can be changed to Ctrl+TAB and CTRL+Shift+TAB on either Windows or Linux as that is hard coded to switch tabs by last used rather than by display order.

Comment: Also, if you're using a macbook (no pgUp or pgDown) you can do cmd+fn+upArrow or cmd+fn+downArrow

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> ?

Comment: Yeah but it jumps weird. I want to jump to the left or right.

Comment: This shortcut jumps in last used order.

Answer (score 3):

To update Spoonface's answer for NetBeans 7.0.1 on Mac.

```
NetBeans -> Preferences -> Keymap

Next Tab = ALT+Meta+RIGHT
Left Tab = ALT+Meta+LEFT
```

That will match a bunch of other apps on Mac OSX such as Google Chrome and Skype.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, I know - but seems to fit here... There seems to confusion, some people like to switch to left/right tab, others (like me) wanting to switch to the most-recently-used tab.
The latter would be ctrl-Tab, but on OSX it does not seem to work properly. The list wich all previous tabs comes up, but I do not manage to select anything but the previous tab... I would expect that while holding ctrl and pressing tab repeatedly would go further down in list, which does not happen (at least on my machine).
This is netbeans 7 on OSX Lion.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is the same key mapping as in Textmate:

NetBeans -> Preferences -> Keymap, put "tab" in the search box and change the following:

```
Next Tab: Shift+Meta+CLOSE_BRACKET
Left Tab: Shift+Meta+OPEN_BRACKET
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2015
Netbeans 8.0.2

for MacOS:

still

*Shift + Control + tab*

*Shift + Control + tab*